Python import on sub-package results in "no module named..." error
Although there are a number of import related questions, I haven't found one that directly addresses my question.
I have installed some packages in the default Site Packages folder and it has a structure similar to this...
Site Packages
|--packageA
|----_init_.py
|----sub-packageB
|------_init_.py
|------fileB1.py
|----sub-packageC
|------_init_.py
|------fileC1.py

The site packages folder is added to the module search path automatically.
Now in fileB1.py, if I call import sub-packageB, I get a no module named sub-packageB error. I know I can do from packageA import sub-packageB.
So my question is: does the folder containing the first module/package mentioned in an import statement be explicitly referenced in the module search path? e.g. (1) if I have import sub-packageB, should path to folder sub-packageB be explicitly on module search path (2) if I have from sub-packageC import fileC1, should path to folder sub-packageC be explicitly on module search path (3) if I have import packageA.sub-packageB, should path to folder packageA be explicitly on module search path?
Thanks.

Don't really understand the question, perhaps try rephrasing. Some info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site

I think the answer is "yes".

Definitely yes. Otherwise you would be in namespace pollution hell. You can play with path configuration files described in the link above if useful.

Thanks very much for the confirmations.
